# Custom post type url rewriting

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I am rewriting the url of CPT 'entertainment' to /entertainment/%year%/%monthnum%/%post_id%/ It is re-writing but gives 404 not found error. How can I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite');
function my_rewrite() {
global $wp_rewrite;
    $entertainment_structure = '/entertainment/%year%/%monthnum%/%post_id%/';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%entertainment%", '([^/]+)', "entertainment=");
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('entertainment', $entertainment_structure, false);
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

// Add filter to plugin init function
add_filter('post_type_link', 'entertainment_permalink', 10, 3);   
// Adapted from get_permalink function in wp-includes/link-template.php
function entertainment_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $rewritecode = array(
        '%year%',
        '%monthnum%',
        '%day%',
        '%hour%',
        '%minute%',
        '%second%',
        $leavename? '' : '%post_id%',
        '%post_id%',
        '%category%',
        '%author%',
        $leavename? '' : '%post_id%',
    );

    if ( '' != $permalink && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')) ) {
        $unixtime = strtotime($post->post_date);

        $category = '';
        if ( strpos($permalink, '%category%') !== false ) {
            $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
            if ( $cats ) {
                usort($cats, '_usort_terms_by_ID'); // order by ID
                $category = $cats[0]->slug;
                if ( $parent = $cats[0]->parent )
                    $category = get_category_parents($parent, false, '/', true) . $category;
            }
            // show default category in permalinks, without
            // having to assign it explicitly
            if ( empty($category) ) {
                $default_category = get_category( get_option( 'default_category' ) );
                $category = is_wp_error( $default_category ) ? '' : $default_category->slug;
            }
        }

        $author = '';
        if ( strpos($permalink, '%author%') !== false ) {
            $authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);
            $author = $authordata->user_nicename;
        }

        $date = explode(" ",date('Y m d H i s', $unixtime));
        $rewritereplace =
        array(
            $date[0],
            $date[1],
            $date[2],
            $date[3],
            $date[4],
            $date[5],
            $post->ID,
            $post->ID,
            $category,
            $author,
            $post->ID,
        );
        $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);
    } else { // if they're not using the fancy permalink option
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

If I replace $entertainment_structure = '/entertainment/%year%/%monthnum%/%post_id%/'; with $entertainment_structure = '/entertainment/%year%/%monthnum%/%entertainment%/';  it works fine

Comment: Did you flush your permalinks after you made the update? I see reference to `flush_rewrite_rules( true );` in your code but I don't think it's firing at the right time. You can trigger it manually through the dashboard if you just click to re-save your permalink structure at Setting - > Permalinks.

Comment: Yes i've flush my permalink but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't have time to fully test your code but thought that perhaps the permalinks needed flushed again. Since that is not the issue I do not have another suggestion at the moment. Hopefully someone else can come by and spot the problem for you. Good luck figuring this out!

Comment: no test needed. Just read the docs. Provided links say the exact needed info.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to hook init, but either register_activation_hook() it, if its a plugin or use after_switch_theme if its a theme (its important to either deactivate/reactivate the plugin or switch themes in order for your rewrites to apply). <= further read [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Flushing_Rewrite_on_Activation)

You might want to have a read of [the rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)